# How to store cross-application config?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I want to store basic information for a action script flex app. Normally I would just have a simple application.ini file where this config resides. Is there an inherent way that I can store this kind of information so that when I close an application and open it again, it knows what I changed a variable to? Ideally, without having any config files lying around? Perhaps it can store it in registry or another way?

Answer (score 2):

> Ideally, without having any config files lying around?

Shared object will help you to store some information. I don't know how big is your data, but [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) is great for storing flags and states.

> The SharedObject class is used to read and store limited amounts of data on a user's computer or on a server. Shared objects offer real-time data sharing between multiple client SWF files and objects that are persistent on the local computer or remote server. Local shared objects are similar to browser cookies and remote shared objects are similar to real-time data transfer devices.